# Analog of Sherman–Morrison matrix inversion formula for $(A-bx^T)^T (A-bx^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, positive-definite, cholesky-decomposition

Let $A$ be a real $n \times d$ matrix, $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$.  I'd like to find a simple formula for$$
F(\vec{x}) = \left(\left(A-\vec{b}\vec{x}^T\right)^T \left(A-\vec{b}\vec{x}^T\right)\right)^{-1}.
$$
My go-to resource for matrix formulas, [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), doesn't have this.

I'm thinking of $A$ and $\vec{b}$ as constants and of $\vec{x}$ as a variable.  I'm also interested in the case $n \gg d$.  I would like to precompute things so that I can make many calls to $F(\vec{x})$ with run times that are independent of $n$.  There is an obvious way to do this:$$
F(\vec{x}) \doteq \left(C - \vec{x} \vec{c}^T - \vec{c} \vec{x}^T + \vec{x}\vec{x}^T\right)^{-1},
$$
where $$
C \doteq A^T A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}\quad\text{and}\quad \vec{c} \doteq \vec{b}^T A \in \mathbb{R}^d.
$$
This solves the problem, but it seems like one could do more.  E.g., the [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) tells us
$$
\left(C + \vec{x}\vec{x}^T\right)^{-1} = C^{-1} - \frac{C^{-1}\vec{x}\vec{x}^TC^{-1}}{1+\vec{x}^TC^{-1}\vec{x}}.
$$
This allows us to see explicitly how the inverse depends on $\vec{x}$.  In principle, we could use Sherman–Morrison repeatedly to get a formula for $F(\vec{x})$, but this turns into a mess of algebra.  Usually I'd ask Mathematica to simplify that type of thing, but I've never found a good way to get Mathematica to do noncommutative algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative to repeatedly applying the Sherman-Morrison formula (in general, actually) is to use the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity). In particular, we can write $F = A^TA + UV$, where
$$
U = -\pmatrix{\vec x & \vec c}, \quad V = \pmatrix{\vec c - \vec x & \vec x}^T.
$$
The "mess of algebra" that you refer to is reduced to multiplying by the inverse of a certain $2 \times 2$ matrix.

For another formulation, you could write $F = A^TA + UKV$, where
$$
U = V^T = \pmatrix{\vec x & \vec c}, \quad K = \pmatrix{1 & -1\\-1 & 0}.
$$
To wit, we end up finding
$$
\begin{align}
F^{-1} &= [A^TA]^{-1} - [A^TA]^{-1}\pmatrix{\vec x & \vec c}
\\ & \qquad (K^{-1} + \pmatrix{\vec x & \vec c}^T[A^TA]^{-1}\pmatrix{\vec x & \vec c})^{-1}\pmatrix{\vec x & \vec c}^T[A^TA]^{-1}.
\end{align}
$$
The inverse of $K$ is of course easy to compute:
$$
K^{-1} = \pmatrix{0&-1\\-1&-1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you Ben.  Yes, this is the simplification I was looking for.  I omitted a factor of $|\vec{b}|^2$ from the $\vec{x}\vec{x}^T$ term in $F(\vec{x})$, but this just multiplies the diagonals of $K$ and $K^{-1}$ by $|\vec{b}|$.